# Convert Wikipedia/MediaWiki's code into HTML using python

Tags: python, parsing, mediawiki

I am trying to grab content from Wikipedia and use the HTML of the article. Ideally I would also like to be able to alter the content (eg, hide certain infoboxes etc).

I am able to grab page content using [mwclient](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient):

```
>>> import mwclient
>>> site = mwclient.Site('en.wikipedia.org')
>>> page = site.Pages['Samuel_Pepys']
>>> print page.text()
{{Redirect|Pepys}}
{{EngvarB|date=January 2014}}
{{Infobox person
...
```

But I can't see a relatively simple, lightweight way to translate this wikicode into HTML using python.

- [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is too much for my needs.
- I could just scrape the original page using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) but that doesn't seem like a particularly elegant solution.
- [mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) might help in the process, but I can't quite tell from the documentation if it gives me anything I need and don't already have.
- I can't see an obvious solution on the [Alternative Parsers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) page.

What have I missed?

**UPDATE:** [I wrote up what I ended up doing, following the discussion below](http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2015/03/25/wikipedia-parsing.php).

Comment: What do you mean "translate into HTML"? The pages you have downloaded  are already in HTML.  You might need to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: I thought I was being specific. I haven't downloaded any "pages". I've queried the Wikipedia API and fetched content that is in MediaWiki's markup, as shown in the example. I would like to translate that into HTML.

Comment: Ah.  I see. Well if you are only grabbing the content from MediaWiki and it's not already in an HTML format that you like then it would be up to you to build the HTML to include that content into.  Honestly BeautifulSoup is a great module and I have used it in many of my applications.  It would already pass you complete HTML that you are free to modify as you wish (hide certain infoboxes, etc).

Comment: Yes, you might be right. I was just surprised that I couldn't find a simple way to turn MediaWiki code into HTML; I thought it would be a reasonably common need. Scraping a web page, even with something as nice as Beautiful Soup, feels like a last resort, especially when there's an API.

Comment: Well there is an API for grabbing a content - not an API for generating HTML because that will be highly relative to the needs of the application. You could build your own HTML shell and use the API to grab the content the just "include" the content into a designated <div> tag in your shell.

Comment: I gave a short example in an answer of what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I realise the API is not for generating HTML. That's why I want a way to turn the content from the API into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
page="""<html>
your pretty html here
<div id="for_api_content">%s</div>
</html>"""
```

Now you can grab your raw content with your API and just call

`generated_page = page%api_content`

This way you can design any HTML you want and just insert the API content in a designed spot.

Those APIs that you are using are designed to return raw content so it's up to you to style how you want the raw content to be displayed.

**UPDATE**

Since you showed me the actual output you are dealing with I realize your dilemma.  However luckily for you there are modules that already parse and convert to HTML for you.

There is one called [mwlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mwlib/0.15.14) that will parse the wiki and output to HTML, PDF, etc.  You can install it with pip using the [install instructions](http://mwlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installation-of-mwlib-with-pip-easy-install).  This is probably one of your better options since it was created in cooperation between Wikimedia Foundation and PediaPress.

Once you have it installed you can use the [`writer`](http://mwlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals.html#the-writer-function) method to do the dirty work.

`def writer(env, output, status_callback, **kwargs): pass`

Here are the docs for this module: http://mwlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

And you can set [attributes](http://mwlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals.html#attributes) on the `writer` object to set the filetype (HTML, PDF, etc).

```
writer.description = 'PDF documents (using ReportLab)'
writer.content_type = 'application/pdf'
writer.file_extension = 'pdf'
writer.options = {
    'coverimage': {
        'param': 'FILENAME',
        'help': 'filename of an image for the cover page',
    }
}
```

I don't know what the rendered html looks like but I would imagine that it's close to the actual wiki page.  But since it's rendered in code I'm sure you have control over modifications as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you underestimate the complexity of Wikipedia content. Just putting the raw content from the API within some HTML (which I think is what you're suggesting) is no use. eg, you can see the raw content here: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Samuel_Pepys&action=edit

Comment: I found the best option for what you want.  I updated my answer.  It takes wiki input and can output in a variety of formats (html, pdf, odt, xml, etc).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. I think mwlib is going to be overkill for what I need. You may have been right earlier on, now backed up by @Tgr, that just grabbing the HTML with BeautifulSoup will be the simplest after all. I honestly thought what I wanted to do would be easier!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with HTML parsing, page content is reasonably semantic (`class="infobox"` and such), and there are classes explicitly meant to demarcate content which should not be displayed in alternative views (the first rule of the [print stylesheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Print.css) might be interesting).

That said, if you really want to manipulate wikitext, the best way is to fetch it, use `mwparserfromhell` to drop the templates you don't like, and use the [parse API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse) to get the modified HTML. Or use the [Parsoid API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/API) which is a partial reimplementation of the parser returning XHTML/RDFa which is richer in  semantic elements.

At any rate, trying to set up a local wikitext->HTML converter is by far the hardest way you can approach this task.

Comment: Thanks Tgr. I really thought what I wanted would be simpler. I realise wikitext is much more complicated but I didn't realise it would, apparently be so much more complicated than being able to pass some text to a simple method in a simple module and getting HTML back. Looks like grabbing the HTML with BeautifulSoup will be the most hassle-free way after all.

Comment: One problem with wikitext is that it was never properly specified and is defined mostly as a huge set of regular expressions which is not fun to replicate in a library. There is a test suite covering most of the usage seen in practice but not all the edge cases; even the parse API and the Parsoid API (which is Wikipedia's own parser reimplementation in node.js) disagree on the rendering of maybe 0.1% of the pages.

Comment: The other problem is that wikitext includes a template system and various extension mechanisms, some of them heavily used on Wikipedia (e.g. using scripts written in Lua to resolve templates dynamically). So any parser that hopes to deal with Wikipedia page content needs to include a Lua compiler, amongst other things. You can avoid most of the complexity by asking the server for the expanded wikitext (with templates transcluded, scripts evaluated etc) but that's a very low-level view and not very useful for manipulation (certainly less useful than HTML).

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my naivety I'd assumed it was like, say, a really complicated Markdown or BBCode! Obviously there's a lot, lot more to it. It's a shame there's not an API for grabbing the rendered HTML, which would at least feel slightly more robust than scraping rendered pages.

Comment: You can just append `action=render` to the URL (see [full documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Actions)). If you prefer a proper API, the parse API can take a page name or ID instead of arbitrary wikitext.

Comment: Thanks. `action=render` seems a little less error prone than scraping the whole page would be. And something [like this with the API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Samuel_Pepys&prop=text) does indeed get me the parsed text of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The mediawiki API contains a (perhaps confusingly named) **parse** action that in effect renders wikitext into HTML. I find that mwclient's faithful mirroring of the API structure sometimes actually gets in the way. There's a [good example of just using requests to call the API to "parse" (aka render) a page given its title](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#Python).